# MySQLs' At Time Zone Convertion

Tags: mysql, postgresql, datetime, timezone, date-conversion

Is there a function in MySQL like in Postgres where I can convert the current timestamp to another timezone?

In Postgres, I do this like these:

```
 SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
```

and it converts it on its own. How do I do this in MySQL? is there anyway?

Thanks

Comment: SIDE NOTE :  `Postgres` instead of `Postgre`, [PostgreSql - Tag Info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved! HAH!

Anyway, I used this:

```
 SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),SUBSTRING(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP), 1, 6),'-05:00') AS est_timezone
```

Basically the query interprets as:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'-08:00','-05:00') AS est_timezone
```

I finally got my current timezone which is -08:00 and will convert it to -05:00. This way, I can now proceed with my previous query to making it a VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CONVERT_TZ()` for this.

**Syntax**:

```
CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)
```

`CONVERT_TZ()` converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by `from_tz` to the time zone given by `to_tz` and returns the resulting value.

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),@@session.time_zone,'-08:00');
```

Here is the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

`now()` -the current time

`@@session.time_zone` -gives the current time zone(local)

`-08:00` -required format in PST.

Comment: Also check this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql).

Comment: from that query, would that mean the now() value is in GMT? what if it is not in GMT?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Unfortunately this cannot be made a view because of the variable used @@session.time_zone. is there a way for this to be a view?

Comment: It was because of the `PST`. Format was really the time difference(`-08:00`).